# Selenium Webdriver 3.3.1 gecko driver 0.18 Firefox 55.0.03 URL not opening

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

trying to launch firefox browser using Selenium Webdriver 3.3.1 gecko driver 0.18 Firefox 55.0.03 URL is not opening.I am getting below error:

```
 1504590431182  geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:17925 Sep 05,
 2017 11:17:11 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
 createSession INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's
 Law holds true on the remote end 1504590431839 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser  \\?\C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args["-marionette"] 1504590433890 addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed:
 [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057
 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057
 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame ::
 resource://gre/modules/FilJavaScerUitpitl se.rjrsomr :: :r
 eFsioluerUctei:l/s/_ggreet/Dmiord u:l:e sl/iAnded o7n0M"a n
 adgaetra.:j snmo,]  lSitnaec k1 5t9r6a:ce: 
 NFSi_lEeRURtOiRl_sN_OgTe_tIDNiIrT(I)A@LrIeZsEoDu:r
 cAed:d/o/ngMraen/amgoedru liess /nFoitl eiUntiitlisa.ljiszme:d7 0  <
 FileUtils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 <
 validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:656 <
 startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:816 <
 startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3122 <
 observe()@jar:file://///%3F/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.ja!/components/addonManager.js:65
 1504590434086  Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette JavaScript
 error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2465:
 NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized JavaScript
 error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 3137: TypeError:
 AddonManagerInternal._getProviderByName(...) is undefined
 1504590435547  Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 54969
 1504590435588  Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 54969 Sep 05, 2017
 11:17:16 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
 INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol. Sep 05, 2017
 11:17:16 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
 INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection Exception in
 thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable
 to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities
 [{marionette=true,
 firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@71e53b,
 browserName=firefox,
 moz:firefoxOptions=org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions@71e53b,
 version=, platform=ANY}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
 Build info: version: Driver info: driver.version:
 FirefoxDrive
```

please provide solutions for this.

Comment: Upgraded to latest selenium binding and then test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are seeing says it all `Build info: version: Driver info: driver.version:`. Your build info & version are not getting captured and printed by gecko driver. The main reason is **`Selenium`**, **`GeckoDriver`** & **`Mozilla Firefox Browser`** versions are not not compatible across your `Test Environment`.

You have mentioned `Selenium Webdriver 3.3.1 gecko driver 0.18 Firefox 55.0.03`

The release notes of geckodriver v0.18.0 clearly mentions the following dependency:

> **`Note that geckodriver v0.16.0 is only compatible with Selenium 3.4 and
>   greater.`**

As you are trying to use `Selenium v3.3.1` through `geckodriver v0.18.0` hence you see **`SessionNotCreatedException`**.

Answer (score 0):

Download latest version of selenium jar files i.e 3.5 and try it. As I read you used the geckodriver v0.18 so use latest jar for that.

Answer (score 0):

Download the selenium latest stable version i.e selenium 3.5.3 and create the driver as below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",geckoDriverPath);
FirefoxProfile ffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffProfile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false);
FirefoxOptions options=new FirefoxOptions();
options.setProfile(ffProfile);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Download the latest geckoDriver from below link.

[Link to download geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

In the code below line is to solve the issue with browser crashing while quitting the driver.

```
ffProfile.setPreference("browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2", false);
```